# React - access exported const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am trying to access an `exported const`:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

function Home (products) {
  return (
   <Component products={products}>
  )
}

export function getServerSideProps() {
  const state = store.getState()

  const { products, loading } = state.productList

  console.log('serverProps products:')
  console.log(products)

  return {props: {products: products, loading: loading}}
}

export default connect(getServerSideProps)(Home)
```

`getServerSideProps()` needs to be exported and it needs to be used in `connect(getServerSideProps)(Home)`. when i remove the export from `getServerSideProps()` the `connect(getServerSideProps)(Home)`. but it needs to be exported as well for server-side-rendering.

**error:**

[image: error]

Comment: `export async function  getServerSideProps (){}` it should be a `async` `export`

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar There's nothing `async` in the question?

Comment: @Bergi it doesn't matter if there is anything `asyncchronous` inside the function or not, next will detect `getServerSideProps ` only if it is exported as `async`. please check at the nextjs docs inside **technical details**  [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering).